# trying to sum select rows for multiple instances

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a query setup like follows:

```
  PEmpID  /  PEmplye  /  PPay  /  PTip  /  BEmpID  /  BEmplye  /  BPay  /  BTip
    17    /    Desi   /  4.80  /  0.00  /    06    /   Mike    /  5.10  /  0.00
    01    /    Sally  /  2.40  /  0.80  /    06    /   Mike    /  2.55  /  0.85
    01    /    Sally  /  2.80  /  0.80  /    01    /   Sally   /  2.98  /  0.85
    17    /    Desi   /  2.40  /  0.80  /    06    /   Mike    /  2.55  /  0.85
```

I need the results of:

```
  ID   /  NAME  /  PPay  /  PTip  /  BPay  /  BTip
  01   /  Sally /  5.20  /  1.60  /  2.98  /  0.85
  06   /  Mike  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  10.20 /  1.70
  17   /  Desi  /  7.20  /  0.80  /  0.00  /  0.00
```

What I have tried is not working:

```
        EDITED & UPDATED
```

The suggestion was brought up to use an UNION query.
I have 4 select queries: qryTESTppay, qryTESTbpay, qryTESTdpay & qryTESTgpay. Each of these are returning the exact numbers needed as follows:

```
  ID  /  NAME  /  PPay  /  PTip  /  BPay  /  BTip
  01  /  Sally /  5.20  /  1.60  /  Rand  /  Rand
  06  /  Mike  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  Rand  /  Rand
  17  /  Desi  /  2.40  /  0.80  /  Rand  /  Rand
```

And,

```
  ID  /  NAME  /  PPay  /  PTip  /  BPay  /  BTip  
  01  /  Sally /  Rand  /  Rand  /  2.98  /  0.85
  06  /  Mike  /  Rand  /  Rand  /  10.20 /  1.70
  17  /  Desi  /  Rand  /  Rand  /  0.00  /  0.00
```

And so on for the remaining 2 queries, where Rand=Random Numbers.

My UNION query came out like follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW qryAllEmployee.ID, 
                   qryAllEmployee.NAME, 
                   Sum(qryTESTpayroll.PPay) AS Weekly_PPay, 
                   Sum(qryTESTpayroll.PTip) AS Weekly_PTip, 
                   0 AS Weekly_BPay, 
                   0 AS Weekly_BTip, 
                   0 AS Weekly_DPay, 
                   0 AS Weekly_DTip, 
                   0 AS Weekly_GPay, 
                   0 AS Weekly_GTip
FROM qryAllEmployee LEFT JOIN qryTESTpayroll ON qryAllEmployee.ID = qryTESTpayroll.PEmpID
GROUP BY qryAllEmployee.ID, qryAllEmployee.NAME
UNION
SELECT DISTINCTROW qryAllEmployee.ID, 
                   qryAllEmployee.NAME, 
                   0 AS Weekly_PPay, 
                   0 AS Weekly_PTip, 
                   Sum(qryTESTpayroll.BPay) AS Weekly_BPay, 
                   Sum(qryTESTpayroll.BTip) AS Weekly_BTip, 
                   0 AS Weekly_DPay, 
                   0 AS Weekly_DTip, 
                   0 AS Weekly_GPay, 
                   0 AS Weekly_GTip
FROM qryAllEmployee LEFT JOIN qryTESTpayroll ON qryAllEmployee.ID = qryTESTpayroll.BEmpID
GROUP BY qryAllEmployee.ID, qryAllEmployee.NAME
UNION
SELECT DISTINCTROW qryAllEmployee.ID, 
                   qryAllEmployee.NAME, 
                   0 AS Weekly_PPay, 
                   0 AS Weekly_PTip, 
                   0 AS Weekly_BPay, 
                   0 AS Weekly_BTip, 
                   Sum(qryTESTpayroll.DPay) AS Weekly_DPay, 
                   Sum(qryTESTpayroll.DTip) AS Weekly_DTip, 
                   0 AS Weekly_GPay, 
                   0 AS Weekly_GTip
FROM qryAllEmployee LEFT JOIN qryTESTpayroll ON qryAllEmployee.ID = qryTESTpayroll.DEmpID
GROUP BY qryAllEmployee.ID, qryAllEmployee.NAME
UNION
SELECT DISTINCTROW qryAllEmployee.ID, 
                   qryAllEmployee.NAME, 
                   0 AS Weekly_PPay, 
                   0 AS Weekly_PTip, 
                   0 AS Weekly_BPay, 
                   0 AS Weekly_BTip, 
                   0 AS Weekly_DPay, 
                   0 AS Weekly_DTip, 
                   Sum(qryTESTpayroll.GPay) AS Weekly_GPay, 
                   Sum(qryTESTpayroll.GTip) AS Weekly_GTip
FROM qryAllEmployee LEFT JOIN qryTESTpayroll ON qryAllEmployee.ID = qryTESTpayroll.GEmpID
GROUP BY qryAllEmployee.ID, qryAllEmployee.NAME;
```

I am getting the results back stacked on top of each other like so:

```
  ID  /  NAME  /  PPay  /  PTip  /  BPay  /  BTip  /  Dpay  /  DTip  /  GPay  /  GTip
  01  /  Sally /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /**63.70*/**33.51**
  01  /  Sally /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /**9.00**/**2.16**/  0.00  /  0.00
  01  /  Sally /  0.00  /  0.00  /**3.40**/**0.76**/  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00
  01  /  Sally /**26.00*/**5.00**/  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00
  06  /  Mike  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00
  06  /  Mike  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00
  06  /  Mike  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /**25.65*/**4.82**/  0.00  /  0.00
  06  /  Mike  /  0.00  /  0.00  /**42.51*/**6.70**/  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00
  17  /  Desi  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00
  17  /  Desi  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /**68.61*/**31.65**
  17  /  Desi  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /**13.95*/**0.90**/  0.00  /  0.00
  17  /  Desi  /**17.20*/**2.00**/  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00  /  0.00
```

The numbers are all correct.
But i need them to be 1 row each.

What else am I missing to accomplish this??

Comment: sir, why not you practice these things on mysql, oracle, postgres, mssql etc for true sql operations.

Comment: @ArifMustafa because I'm working on a MSaccess DB. Would this other options you mention be of help to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a *union* query:

```
Select 
    PEmpID As ID,
    PEmplye As [Name],
    PPay,
    PTip,
    0 As BPay,
    0 As BTip
From
    YourQuery
Union All
Select 
    BEmpID As ID,
    BEmplye As [Name],
    0 As PPay,
    0 As PTip,
    BPay,
    BTip
From
    YourQuery
```

Save this query and use it as source in another query:

```
Select 
    ID, [Name], Sum(PPay), Sum(PTip), Sum(BPay), Sum(BTip)
From
    Query1
Group By
    ID, [Name]
```

Comment: is there a way to get those results back with one row each for each employee with all the numbers in one the one row?

Comment: Or I guess I should ask, is the only to get the results in 1 row, by adding another query??

Comment: The result will be one row per ID-Name.

Comment: Somethings not right then. Mine are stacked like i show at the bottom of my question. I noticed you are using UNION ALL, but when i use ALL, i get 1 line per ID, per Date, BUT the numbers do not match up. In fact all the number are in the PPay & PTip columns.

Comment: Can't tell. There is no date field in your sample data.